# How to get "10:20 AM IST" from that code using xpath in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
<div class="game-date-time">
  <span data-date="2017-03-11T04:50Z" data-behavior="date_time">
  <span class="time game-time" data-dateformat="time1" data-showtimezone="true">10:20 AM IST</span>
  <span class="game-date" data-dateformat="date12">11 March 2017</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Plz, provide more information.

Comment: What have u tried , ? What happened when u use the class as xpath locator ?

Comment: `//div[class='game-date-time']/span[class='game-time].text()`

Comment: Depending on the language used .text() changes it could be .text,.getText() , text()

Answer (score 1):

As per the XML code snippet you have given, please try the below xpath locator-

```
./div[contains(@class,'game-date-time')]//span[contains(@class,'time game-time')].getAttribute('value')
```

This xpath will look inside the div containing the class 'game-date-time' and then search for the span with class 'time game-time' to get the attribute 'value', which is 10:20 AM IST in this case. You could also use getText(), getAttribute('innerText') or getAttribute('textContent') instead of getAttribute('value').